# Bar graph doesn't fill the Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart of a list of a variable number of "Accumulators", which have a person's name and three percentages which always add up to 100. But when I have a large number of entries in the list, all the bars are crowded to the left side of the graph.

Here's the code:

```
per_unreviewed = np.array([p.accum_per_unreviewed for p in accumulators])
per_reviewed = np.array([p.accum_per_reviewed for p in accumulators])
per_signed_off = np.array([p.accum_per_signed_off for p in accumulators])
fig = Figure(facecolor="w", figsize=(15, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ind = np.arange(len(accumulators))
logger.debug("len(acc) = %d, ind = %s", len(accumulators), ind)
width = 0.45
p1 = ax.bar(ind, per_signed_off, width, color="g")
p2 = ax.bar(ind, per_reviewed, width, color="b", bottom=per_signed_off)
p3 = ax.bar(ind, per_unreviewed, width, color="r",
            bottom=per_signed_off + per_reviewed)
ax.set_title(title)
ax.set_ylabel("Percent by status")
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 101, 20))
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2.0)
ax.set_xticklabels(
    [p.person for p in accumulators],
    rotation='vertical', clip_on=False)

fig.tight_layout()
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.7, box.height])

if (len(p1) > 0 or len(p2) > 0 or len(p3) > 0):
    ax.legend(
        (p1[0], p2[0], p3[0]),
        ('Signed Off', 'Reviewed', 'Unreviewed'),
        loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), borderaxespad=0
    )

canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
outstr = StringIO.StringIO()
canvas.print_png(outstr)
```

And the result
[image: big bar graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the x axis range? You have the ticks and a figure size, but nothing that tells the plot the range of x.

I don't use subplots myself, but is there something like ax.set_xlim([]) or ax.xlim() that does this?

Update from Paul Tomblin: I tried those suggestions and they didn't help, but they did point me to the right idea:

```
ax.set_xbound(lower=0, upper=len(accumulators))
```